How can I connect an Azure DevOps Microsoft-hosted agent pool to an AWS Network Security Group (NSG) that blocks public IPs?
I am using the Microsoft-hosted agent pool to run an Azure pipeline. In the pipeline YAML, I have included a task (task: SSH@0) to connect to an AWS EC2 instance. However, the AWS Network Security Group is configured to block public IP addresses. I attempted to register the Azure DevOps public IPs in the AWS NSG, but this approach did not work.
I want to establish a connection between Azure Pipeline and an AWS EC2 instance by adding the Azure DevOps public IP range to the AWS Network Security Group, which currently blocks all public IPs (0.0.0.0/0).

I’ve tried setting up a service connection between Azure DevOps and an AWS EC2 instance, but it didn’t work.

I’ve also added the Azure IP Ranges and Service Tags for the public cloud to the AWS NSG inbound rules, but it didn’t help.



Hi Pandurang Vadane, welcome to stack overflow. I've seen some Azure VMs users run into similar issues before and use a workaround similar to my answer, which is to dynamically add the agent IP to the Azure VM.  Looking forward to hearing if it works in this issue since I don't have an AWS account to test.

You can refer to the following steps to dynamically add agent IP to AWS Network Security Group.

Get the IP of the current agent and set it as variable.
Add the IP to the AWS Network Security Group with the AWSCLI task with the aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress command. Here is the sample of the command.
Run the SSH task to connect to an AWS EC2 instance.
Remove the IP to the AWS Network Security Group with the AWSCLI task with the aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress command. Here is the sample of the command.

Here is possible sample YAML :
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
# Get the IP of the current agent and set it as variable.
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Get the IP of current agent
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $IP= Invoke-RestMethod http://ipinfo.io/json | Select -exp ip
      $IP
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=IP]$IP"

- task: AWSCLI@1
  displayName: 'Add IP to AWS Security Group'
  inputs:
    awsCredentials: 'your-service-connection'
    regionName: 'your-region'
    awsCommand: 'ec2'
    awsSubCommand: 'authorize-security-group-ingress'
    awsArguments: '--group-id your-security-group-id --protocol tcp --port 22 --cidr $(IP)/32'


# Connect to an AWS EC2 instance with SSH task and do what you need to do.
- task: SSH@0
  inputs:
    sshEndpoint: 'your-ssh-endpoint'
    runOptions: 'commands'
    commands: 'your-commands'
  

- task: AWSCLI@1
  displayName: 'Remove IP from AWS Security Group'
  inputs:
    awsCredentials: 'your-service-connection'
    regionName: 'your-region'
    awsCommand: 'ec2'
    awsSubCommand: 'revoke-security-group-ingress'
    awsArguments: '--group-id your-security-group-id --protocol tcp --port 22 --cidr $(IP)/32'

